# jQuery SlideUp / SlideDown strange behaviour on IE8 and 9

Tags: jquery, slide

I have a simple wrapper `<div>` that holds the search form:

[image]

I can slide it up / down (so I can have more space for the results and not to clutter the result view), but in **IE8** and **IE9** (cant test it with IE7 yet), it slides ok but the **buttons remain on the page until the slide is completed**, just like:

[image]

this does not happen in **Chrome 14**, **Safari 5.1** and **Opera 11.11**

[image]

When the slide completes, it's ok

[image]

Is there anything that I'm missing with the `slideUp` and `slideDown`?

P.S. `slideToggle` acts just the same.

---

wrapper and buttons use `position: relative;`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find the bugger, so I ended up hiding the buttons first before sliding up and fading in  after it slides down.

Answer (score 0):

How is the button positioned?
Are they absolute?

SlideUp uses overflow:hiddden and and a set height, so it could be that position:absolute could be overlapping in IE.

THey do disappear when the animation is complete right?

Comment: they do, and they are `position: relative;`

Answer (score 0):

The problem not in jQuery. You need to fix your CSS and markup. Probably `position:relative` for your container can help you, but I'm not sure. We need to take a look on the page structure and css.

Comment: nope.. I mean your container where buttons are placed should have `position:relative`. And of course, if you will use `position:relative` for buttons they will be positioned over your container.

Comment: If I drill up the DOM, the container is the same as all input boxes, and they all slide as expected.

Comment: can you show the styles of element on which you call slideUp?

Comment: set to `div` which you 'slideUp' style `position:relative`